# Updated version of the mysql World database?

Tags: mysql, database

I know it's meant only as a test database, but I can;t find an (updated) copy of the World DB anywhere. The one on the Mysql site is out of date for most countries (presidents/heads of state have changed, etc). Anyone know where this data came from?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like there is an updated version. The source is [Statistics Finland](http://www.stat.fi/worldinfigures), according to [MySQL's setup page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup.html).